# Setting width of BS3 input-group-addon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some trouble when setting the width of BS3 input-group-addon elements that have been both prepended and appended to a text input.  In this case, the width of the input-group-addon elements is set correctly, but the width of the text input no longer fills the width of the container.  However if these is only one input-group-addon that has been either prepended or appended, setting the width works as expected, please see http://jsfiddle.net/asZXU/ for an example.

How do I set the width of BS3 input-group-addon elements that have been both prepended and appended to a text input and still have the text input fill the remaining width of the container?

Note: I have only set the width of the input-group-addon elements using `style="width: 55px;` in the fiddle to be able to demonstrate all variations.  I would ideally like to be able to set the width by doing something like:

```
.input-group-addon {
    width: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks promising: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/D53TE/

Have added a class to the form group with CSS

```
.svX3{
width:100%;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, so simple I can't believe I didn't think if that!

Comment: You have to like simple :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//add this to custom css,

.input-group-addon {
    min-width:100px;
}
```